Scenario probability in portfolio optimization
I have few questions regarding linear programming formulation of expectile-based portfolio optimization. From this article on page 51 the LP algorithm is presented.
And the problems are that I don't really understand the purpose of p vector and few other things that I will mention later. How can we choose probability distribution for this vector? On the other hand CVaR optimization problem does not have this vector defined in its algorithm (page 48 of the same article).
Generally I wanted to approach portfolio optimization with this LP algorithm (page 51) based on fitting copula to individual assets. The procedure would be:
 - Defining training period of portfolio optimization, say 2010-01-01 up to 2015-12-31 and testing period of 2016-01-01-2022-01-01 
 - For every rolling window (window size = 100): 
 - - - Choosing marginal distributions to each of the portfolio assets (N=20 assets for example) from looking at historical returns (how to choose it? arbitrary or with some algorithm? GARCH?)
 - - - Fitting copula to the chosen marginal distributions
 - - - Sampling from this fitted copula to obtain returns of the assets in this time window
 - - - Applying portfolio linear programming optimization algorithm for this window to get optimized weights that will be used to recalculate returns of assets in later time windows (is it correct?) (what about p vector? what probabilites should I apply?)

I also struggle with the purpose of rolling windows. What do I do with the optimized weights of, say, first window, in the second window? I recalculate the returns of the asset as I mentioned in the algorithm sketch or what? I would need some explanations how to "propagate" this algorithm.
